# Synonym/hyponyms/hypernym detection data set

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora, resource-request, synonymy, datasets

I am looking for data sets that I could use to train and benchmark a system  that detects synonyms, hyponyms and hypernyms in a text.

For example, in the sentence

> In statistics, logistic regression, or logit regression, is a regression model where the dependent variable (DV) is categorical.

- *logistic regression* is a synonym of *logit regression*.
- *logistic regression* is a hyponym of *regression model*.

The data set should contain texts annotated with entities and whether they are synonym/hyponyms/hypernym.